# AngularJS + UI Kit

Tags: angularjs, uikit, yii2

I'm new to angularJS, When i use [UIKit](http://getuikit.com/) only its working fine (Yii2). When i use with angularJS the Javascript events like(tab, slider, dropdown, etc) not working.. I don't know what i have missed or is the any dependency i have to add it work this. This is my `app.js` code

`var app = angular.module('nApp', [
    'ui.router',        //
    'ngSanitize',       // sanitize HTML
    'ngAnimate',        // CSS and JavaScript ng-animate
    'ngRoute',          // $routeProvider
    'toaster',          // toasterProvider
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',   // bs-navbar, data-match-route directives
]);` 
And my `AppAsset.php` file is like this,

```
public $css = [
    'uikit/css/uikit.gradient.min.css',
];
public $js = [
    'js/app.js',
    'uikit/js/uikit.min.js',
];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'frontend\assets\AngularAsset',
];
```

In `AngularAsset.php` I have loaded angular related files(css & js).

Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

the reason you are having problems with integrating uikit components into your angularjs project is because uikit components like accordion or slider in your case, are instantiated the moment they are loaded. What this means is that if you place the slider.js file in the header of the first page you load, and your slider is in another html file not loaded yet, say users.html, then the slider.js file will not attach the component to your element in users.html.

If that doesn't clear things up, let me show you what I mean.

This is your index.html (the first html page you load).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <!--loading uikit components in here will not work on other html files -->
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="nApp">
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="container" data-ng-view>
    <!--This is where the other html files will load in, like users.html -->
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is users.html with an accordion component.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.25.0/js/components/accordion.min.js"></script>
<!--This accordion will work-->
     <div class="uk-accordion" data-uk-accordion="{collapse:false}">

    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Title 1</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">content one</div>

    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Title 2</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">content two</div>

    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Title 3</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">content three</div>

</div>
```

To elaborate, the accordion will work in `users.html` because the javascript file `accordion.js` is instantiated when users.html is loaded and so the component can attach to the respected element. 
I hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

An other way is to say at UIkit, to make an 'watcher' on the dom
if you put `data-uk-observe` on the div.

Ui kit will be in place at this moment

Answer (score 1):

Observe the DOM to auto-init new added components, e.g via AJAX.

If you inject dynamic HTML markup into the DOM via JavaScript, just add the **data-uk-observe** attribute to one of the parent elements to auto-initialize UIKit JavaScript components.

Usage

```
<div data-uk-observe>
    <!-- inject your dynamic html here -->
</div>
```

Observe an element via JavaScript

```
UIkit.domObserve('#element', function(element) { /* apply on dom change within element */ })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since AngularJS renders the HTML after the digest cycle, you have to re-render the UI component. Let's say for example for have the UIKit accordion:

```
<div id="myAccordion" 
       data-uk-accordion="{ showfirst: false }" 
       class="uk-accordion"
       data-uk-observe>
```

Then, in the callback method from the controller for re-rendering the UI component you have to invoke:

```
    UIkit.domObserve('#myAccordion', function (element) {
      UIkit.component.boot('accordion');
      UIkit.init(element);
    });
```